# Excel Data Extraction Formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to run a report to evaluate the downtime of devices in a network. The OpManagement report doesn't have any customization available for output reporting. So I am looking for a way to extract the data and convert the results to provide a weekly percentage of availability. All of the formulas fail and only return `#VALUE!`.

For example in cell A1: "Magazine Production line (Total Downtime :3d 2h 8m 23s)"

The formula Should return 55.869% because 3d=259200 Seconds, 2h=7200 Seconds, 8m= 480 Seconds, 23 Seconds which is a total of 266903 seconds over 604800 "seconds per week" or 44.131% Downtime.  One formula will do the conversion but I have to manually extract the "D,H,M,& S first.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("d",A1)),LEFT(A1,FIND("d",A1)-1)*86400,0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("h",A1)),MID(0&A1,FIND("h",0&A1)-2,2)*3600,0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("m",A1)),MID(0&A1,FIND("m",0&A1)-2,2)*60,0)
+IF(ISNUMBER(FIND("s",A1)),MID(0&A1,FIND("s",0&A1)-2,2)/604800)
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: Try evaluating the formula to see the error.  Select the cell in question, and then click on `Formulas` in the ribbon.  In the `Formula Auditing` section, select `Evaluate Formula`.  A new screen will pop up and select one of the command button options to see exactly where the formula fails.

Answer (score 0):

This one took a little work!

Your question formatting was a little off, so I *BELIEVE* this is your intended original cell contents:

```
Magazine Production line (Total Downtime :3d 2h 8m 23s)
```

So, based on that, this formula will pull the amount of days and time out and place them in excel date format.

```
=DATE(0,1,MID(A$1,FIND(" :",A$1)+2,FIND("d ",A$1,FIND(" :",A$1)+2)-FIND(" :",A$1)-2))+TIME(MID(A$1,FIND("d ",A$1)+2,FIND("h ",A$1,FIND("d ",A$1)+2)-FIND("d ",A$1)-2),MID(A$1,FIND("h ",A$1)+2,FIND("m ",A$1,FIND("h ",A$1)+2)-FIND("h ",A$1)-2),MID(A$1,FIND("m ",A$1)+2,FIND("s)",A$1,FIND("m ",A$1)+2)-FIND("m ",A$1)-2))
```

The reason to get this into excel date format is it makes it easier to get a percentage. Since this is all based off of the year 1900, it makes it easy to do the math. If you divide the above formula by 1/7/1900, then you get your percentage:

```
=(DATE(0,1,MID(A$1,FIND(" :",A$1)+2,FIND("d ",A$1,FIND(" :",A$1)+2)-FIND(" :",A$1)-2))+TIME(MID(A$1,FIND("d ",A$1)+2,FIND("h ",A$1,FIND("d ",A$1)+2)-FIND("d ",A$1)-2),MID(A$1,FIND("h ",A$1)+2,FIND("m ",A$1,FIND("h ",A$1)+2)-FIND("h ",A$1)-2),MID(A$1,FIND("m ",A$1)+2,FIND("s)",A$1,FIND("m ",A$1)+2)-FIND("m ",A$1)-2)))/DATE(0,1,7)
```

This comes out to a result of `44.13%` downtime.

Just subtract the whole thing from `1` and you get your final result:

```
=1-((DATE(0,1,MID(A$1,FIND(" :",A$1)+2,FIND("d ",A$1,FIND(" :",A$1)+2)-FIND(" :",A$1)-2))+TIME(MID(A$1,FIND("d ",A$1)+2,FIND("h ",A$1,FIND("d ",A$1)+2)-FIND("d ",A$1)-2),MID(A$1,FIND("h ",A$1)+2,FIND("m ",A$1,FIND("h ",A$1)+2)-FIND("h ",A$1)-2),MID(A$1,FIND("m ",A$1)+2,FIND("s)",A$1,FIND("m ",A$1)+2)-FIND("m ",A$1)-2)))/DATE(0,1,7))
```

Or `55.87%`

Comment: Not knowing your other potential formats, such as when D/H/M/S are zero (are they blank or zeros in the format?) limited my response. If you have additional formats, such as
    Magazine Production line (Total Downtime :2h 23s)

This may take some additional work.